# закрепить ссылку/кнопку в центре видео

Tags: html, css, видео, position, link

Есть видео которое растягивается на 40% экрана, но кнопка выключения звука которая висит поверх видео статична, можно как-то сделать, чтоб она всегда была по центру экрана? (флексбокс не помогает)

вот демо : https://jsfiddle.net/p5c483mp/3/

```
<div class="intercom-content">
  <div class="filter">
    <video class="intercom-video"></video>
    <a class="microphone-btn" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Методов много, а почему не поставить для microphone-btn просто  left:45%; ?   >"по центру экрана " это центр беграунда которую поставили ?

Comment: Не очень удачно написал, по центру видео, а не по центру экрана

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
  .intercom-content {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #e5e9ed;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: table;
  /*max-width: min-content;*/
  width: 40%;
  position: relative; /* это */
}

.intercom-video {
  /*width: 512px;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 384px;
  background-color: #cbcbcb;
}

.filter {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #72879c;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.microphone-btn {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc((100% - 40px) / 2); /* это */
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 0;
  /* background-image: url(./img/microphone-off.svg);*/
  background-color: black;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  /*vertical-align: middle;*/
```

```html
<div class="intercom-content">
  <div class="filter">
    <video class="intercom-video"></video>
    <a class="microphone-btn" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, правда я вопрос криво задал, и забыл спросить про нижний край, но этот же способ для top помог сделать